# Set blank value in primeng pcalendar

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I have a problem with a p-calendar in a priming theme and Angular 2, I want to clean the calendar value after the user selects a date and set a blank value. 
My code:

**Component**

```
<div style="margin-right: -6px"> 
     <p-calendar [(ngModel)]="viewModel.fromDate" [showIcon]="true" readOnlyInputText="true" (click)="restoreValues()"></p-calendar>
</div>
```

**TypeScript file**

```
export class RequestSearcherComponent implements OnInit {


restoreValues(): void {

    this.viewModel.areaIds = [];
    this.viewModel.cedingIds = [];
    this.viewModel.requestType = [];
    this.viewModel.requestResponsible = [];
    this.viewModel.requestStatus = [];
    this.fromDate.setDate(null);
   }
}
```

I tried a lot of methods and ways as the `setDate` that appears in the code.
But doesn't works :(

Can anybody help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Solved!

Is not the best way but works...

**Component**

```
<div>     
     <p-calendar #fromCal [(ngModel)]="value" [showIcon]="true" readOnlyInputText="true"></p-calendar>
</div>
```

**TypeScript file**

```
@Component({
selector: 'app-request-searcher',
templateUrl: './request-searcher.component.html'
})

export class RequestSearcherComponent implements OnInit {

@ViewChild('fromCal') calendarFrom: Calendar;

/** My awesome code... */

restoreValues(): void {

    this.calendarFrom.value = null;
    this.calendarFrom.updateInputfield();

   }
}
```